# Error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function execute()

Tags: php, mysqli

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function execute() in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\LOGIN\validar.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\LOGIN\validar.php on line 14

Este es mi código

```
<?php  session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    header('Location: ../administrador/administrador.php');
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $usuario = $_POST["documento"];
    $contrasena = $_POST["contrasena"];

    require('conexion.php');

    $consulta = $conexion ->prepare('SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE documento=:usuario and contrasena=:contrasena');
    $consulta = execute(array(':usuario'=>$usuario,':contrasena'=>$contrasena));

    $resultado = $consulta ->fecth();
    if($resultado!==false){
        $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
        header('Location: ../administrador/administrador.php');
    }else{
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: hasta donde se deberia ser: `$consulta->execute()`visita el [MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) de php para documentarte

Comment: El único problema es que intenta ejecutar un método `execute` el cuál no existe ya que este pertenece a la consulta preparada en sí, lo único que  debería modificar es llamar a `execute`  de esta forma  `$consulta->execute()`

Comment: Adicionando a lo comentado por Dev. Joel, tienes un error de sintaxis al escribir `$resultado = $consulta ->fecth();` debe ser asi: `$resultado = $consulta->fetch();`

Comment: @Dev.Joel a lo que me referia era a esto `fecth()`, esta mal escrito, siento no haber resaltado correctamente el error.

Comment: @A.Palacio ah es verdad.

Comment: Ya lo solucione muchas muchas gracias... @A.Palacio

Comment: Ya lo solucione muchas muchas gracias... @Dev.Joel

Answer (score 1):

Si ya le diste a conocer los marcadores de usuario y contrasenia, solo debes ejecutar tu consulta de este modo:

```
$consulta = $conexion ->prepare(
                                'SELECT * FROM clientes 
                                 WHERE usuario = ? 
                                 AND contrasena = ?'
                                );
$consulta->bind_param('s', $usuario);
$consulta->bind_param('s', $contrasena);
$consulta->execute();
```

> Donde como puedes observar es acceder al método `execute()`, mas no
>   indicar que tu consulta es igual a dicho método

---

> Como puedes notar también te hace falta hacer el `bind` de cada uno de
>   los valores de tu consulta y asi mismo indicar el tiempo de dato, que
>   en este caso debería ser `s` de `string`

Tambien revisa si documento es el nombre de tu columna o tal vez te equivocaste y era usuario y los marcadores en mysqli debe ser con signos de interrogación

Comment: Solo comentar que no hace falta hacer  `bind` para este caso   , se puede pasar directamente los valores como lo está haciendo el OP _(y si lo hiciera pueden ir en una sola línea)_ , `execute`  puede admitir como parámetro un  `array` con los marcadores de la consulta y  sus valores respectivos.

Comment: entiendo @Dev.Joel gracuas por la observación

Comment: @DevJoel la pregunta ha sido marcada con la etiqueta `mysqli`. Con esta API, si no recuerdo mal, no se pueden pasar los parámetros en el `execute` como sí se puede hacer con PDO. Por tanto, hay que recurrir necesariamente al método `bind_param`. No estoy en capacidad de probarlo ahora, pero estoy casi seguro. Incluso, creo que tampoco se puede usar los marcadores de `:nombre` en `mysqli`, debiéndose usar los marcadores de posición `?` ... Cuando pueda haré las pruebas al respecto.

Comment: @A.Cedano efectivamente fue un error mio al pensar en PDO  cuando la pregunta es de MySQLi _(ha de ser el horario)_ , no se pueden pasar arrays a la función execute y solo aceptan marcadores de posición. Igual es posible hacer el bind en una sola línea .